# Different behavior on android emulator and JVM using RxJava2

Tags: android, junit, rx-java2

Here is a code snippet that is working on an Android emulator but not in Junit tests.

```
 public void startObserving() {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 40)
            .doOnNext(integer -> System.out.println("doOnNext item " + integer + " on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("Consuming item " + integer + " on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Logs in doOnNext() and subscribe() are printed when I am running this method on Android Emulator but not when I run it as a JUnit test.
Can anyone of you amazing people explain to me what I am missing here...

Comment: Can you also provide the code in your test file? It may be relevant to answering this question

Comment: It is the same piece of code from tests. For Android, may be just replace sys out with log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remember that you're dealing with asynchronous code. the tests are running to completion before the subscription actually happens. adding a sleep statement can verify this:

```
@Test
public void startObserving() throws Exception {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 40)
        .doOnNext(integer -> System.out.println("doOnNext item " + integer + " on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("Consuming item " + integer + " on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @hsl for the prompt response. This steered me in the direction I was looking for. Though this does not look like a generic solution as waiting unnecessarily on main thread is not a good idea.
Accepting the answer as this definitely helped me get the reasoning.
tynn 's approach seems more robust but that did not work without other boiler plate code which I am still looking into.

Answer (score 2):

*RxJava* is running streams asynchronously when you provide `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` operators. Thus the tests finish before the stream do.

So for testing purposes you have to synchronize the stream. You can achieve this with `RxJavaPlugins` like:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(sc -> Schedulers.trampoline());
RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler(sc -> Schedulers.trampoline());
```

Comment: thanks for the response. could you please guide me in the right direction for using RxjavaPlugins.. I tried using you code as is in #Before and seperately in the #test method but I got this ExceptionInInitializerError. Appreciate you guys helping out.

Comment: It seems that it's better to use the methods without the _init_ part. Using it for several it might be even suitable to build a custom `Rule`. But handling it in `@Before` should be fine as well.